# MongoDB query result not as expected using Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am facing an issue related to fetching data from MongoDB collection.

I have below collection in MongoDB database:

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
       { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
       { item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 22.85, 30 ] },
       { item: "postcard", qty: 45, tags: ["blue"], dim_cm: [ 10, 15.25 ] }
])
```

I have a below query:

```
db.inventory.find( { dim_cm: { $gt: 25 } } )
```

Result: `{ item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 22.85, 30 ] }`

However, I want the result should be:

```
{ item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 30 ] }
```

Is it possible to get mentioned result. I have tried different ways but unfortunately I am unable to find any solution towards it.

Comment: What are the two values in the array field `dim_cm: [ 22.85, 30] `? And you want the second element only of the array.

Comment: I think result is correct because it have less than and 25 & greater than 25 dim_cm value. When you query 25 greater than It will match second item because it have one item. nothing issue with result

Comment: What if you need to get items witch is greater than 25 once do the query and remove unwanted ones in application level

Comment: @prasad_ yes, I want only second element.

Comment: @SajithVijesekara yes it is correct, but I want the result without 22.85 as it is less then 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use `$filter` in `aggregate` pipeline to filter the array

something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { // to filter the documents 
      dim_cm: { $gt: 25 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      item: 1,
      qty: 1,
      tags: 1,
      dim_cm: {
        $filter: { // to filter the array
          input: "$dim_cm",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $gt: ["$$item", 25]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rQyjZH_Wy8R)

hope it helps